# Associating a file uploaded with Carrierwave_Direct with an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm uploading files directly to S3 using the carrierwave_direct gem and everything is going smoothly. However, when amazon redirects back to the URL specfied in `success_action_redirect`, I'm not associating the uploaded file with the object.

My controller looks like

```
def edit
  @excel_version = ExcelVersion.find(params[:id])
  @uploader = @excel_version.excel_everest_macro
  @uploader.success_action_redirect = edit_admin_excel_version_url
end


def update
  @excel_version = ExcelVersion.find(params[:id])
  @excel_version.assign_attributes(params[:excel_version])
  @excel_version.save
end
```

And I have a hidden form field in my view that looks like
    = form_for @excel_version do |form|
      = form.hidden_field :key

So in my update action I just use `@excel_version.assign_attributes(params[:excel_version])` 
and the key returned by Amazon makes it into the model just fine.  However, the uploader mounted on the @excel_version object doesn't get url and I can't set up a link to then download the file.

Any suggestions on how I can use the S3 parameters returned to me to associate the file with the model as carrierwave would normally do?

Thanks!

P.S. another answer on here suggested reading the carrier_wave direct documentation on github, which I have and have found unhelpful in this respect.

Comment: can you give a little more info regarding the :key value returned? are you successfully saving the key value to @excel_version? if so then why are you having a problem downloading? if you have the key then you should have the proper URL link to the file uploaded...with more info perhaps i can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was that I had the `hidden_field :key` field on the wrong form.  I mistakenly put the field on the `direct_upload_form_for @uploader` form that uploads the file to S3.

Of course, you need the `:key` field on a form that the user returns to *after* posting the file to S3 (ie at the url passed in to the `success_action_redirect` method).  It is there that S3 will return the key in the params and you can associate it with your model.

Thanks for all the helpful suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

To associate the image to the model what you can do is create a method in your controller which would use the params from amazon and create the image link

For example you can do -

```
  def image_url
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => { :filelink => "https://s3.amazonaws.com/#{params[:bucket]}/#{params[:key]}" } }
    end
  end
```

What this code will do is when amazon does a success redirect to image_url method it will use the parameters "bucket" and "key" to create a exact link to your image. (The params which are sent have both key and the bucket name)

Now you can put this image url in the hidden object on your view so that when the form is posted to the server the url also gets posted along with it. Which you can associate to your model.

Hope this helps. It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Could you show how you do the final step: assigning "filelink" to the hidden field in form?